# Why can not cast a double value to Byte object?

Tags: java, object, casting, double, byte

Why can't a primitive value (eg. a double) be cast to an Object (eg. a Byte)?

```
double x = 99;
Byte r = (Byte) x;     // Error: Cannot cast from double to Byte
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 5):

Java will not implicitly narrow a primitive value, e.g. from `double` to `byte`, so that you can explicitly cast it to a `Byte` via a boxing conversion.  This guards against accidental loss of precision.

What you can do is cast the `double` to a `byte` (lowercase) explicitly; then Java will implicitly box the `byte` into a `Byte`.  When you explicitly cast a primitive value to a narrower range type, then you are telling the compiler, "Yes, I'm aware that I might lose precision, but I want this conversion anyway."

```
Byte r = (byte) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not cast from a double to byte because the byte has a range smaller than the double and it does not contain decimals like a double does.

For example: The program does not know what to do to cast 1000.5 to a byte.  A byte has a max of 128 (I believe) and it can not contain a decimal (which is the .5)